# MooTools-Core: uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have this code function:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        var content = CKEDITOR.instances['comment'].getData();
        $('comment').setProperty('value',content)
        e.stop();
        var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
        this.set('send', {onComplete: function(response) { 
            log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
            log.set('html', response);
        }});
        this.send();
    });
});
```

im getting:

> `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

currently using: mootools-core: 1.5.1

Comment: which line? potentially, issues here are around calling a method on a selector which may not have returned an object. eg `log = $('log_res').empty()...` - if it does not find the dom node with the id `log_res`, calling `.empty()` on undefined will throw. this could equally apply to your CKEDITOR since if `.instances['comment']` is undefined, so `.getData()` will also be. so - which line throws? also, if you have jQuery or something on the page, `$.fn.addEvent()` may be undefined. not enough info to solve this. please edit your question and add more info.

Comment: The error throws off right after: `$('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {`

Comment: if the error happens when running this code, you either don't have an id `myForm` or $ is not mootools but jquery. try this: `(function($){ ... your code after domready ... }(document.id));` which will create a closure where $ will be the real value of `document.id`, which is what mootools uses.
if it happens when pressing submit, it's ckeditor.

Comment: yea that definitely worked thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

putting comment into an answer.

it looks as if it's trying to call `.addEvent()` on the chained result of `$` - which normally is an alias for `document.id`. However, if Mootools gets loaded after jQuery, it won't define the `$` and chances are, you are calling it on the `jQuery.fn` prototype.

use a closure pattern around your mootools code:

```
(function($){
    $('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e) {
        var content = CKEDITOR.instances['comment'].getData();
        $('comment').setProperty('value',content)
        e.stop();
        var log = $('log_res').empty().addClass('ajax-loading');
        this.set('send', {onComplete: function(response) { 
            log.removeClass('ajax-loading');
            log.set('html', response);
        }});
        this.send();
    });
}(document.id));
```

this ensures the value of `$` in your mootools code is exactly what you need it to be.

you can also look at `jQuery.noConflict()` to prevent jQuery from exporting to `$` and sticking to `jQuery` only.